# How keep tracking the external program opened in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, psutil

I want open a program (ex: calculator) and keep tracking his process as the pid, name, etc.
But, after calling the subprocess.Popen(), the process id is killed after few time.

So i want to initialize this program and get the process id and other informations **and kill the process only if the user close the application** (in this case, the calculator).

```
import subprocess
import psutil

process = subprocess.Popen('C:\Windows\System32\calc')

while psutil.pid_exists(process.pid):
    print('Process running')
print('Done')
```

Comment: If the user already killed it, there is no need for you to do anything more. I don't think you need `psutil` here, you can just [`poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) to check whether the process object is alive. Probably add a small sleep so you don't do this thousands of times per second.

Comment: Or simply use `subprocess.run()` instead and just wait for it to exit, if your Python code has nothing useful to do in the meantime.

Comment: The propurse here is to get the actual process opened. I dont uderstant well why the process spawn by Popen() is killed even the application still running. In this case, i opened the calculator and the subprocess is gone (after poll() returns 0). But the application Calculator.exe still running on the SO. I want to take this actual process.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I only got Mac right now so the code runs correctly on it. However, I think it will function properly on Windows as well if you insert the file path of the application correctly.

For **Windows**

```
import subprocess 
import psutil 
import time

print(psutil.__version__) # tested on 5.9.0

process = subprocess.Popen('C:\Windows\System32\calc')

# wait a moment to make sure that the app is open 
time.sleep(1)

is_running = True

while is_running:
    # check if the app is running
    is_running = "calc" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter())
    print('Process running')

print('Done')
```

For **MAC**

```
import subprocess
import psutil
import time

print(psutil.__version__) # tested on 5.9.0

process = subprocess.Popen(['open', '/System/Applications/Calculator.app'])

# wait a moment to make sure that the app is open
time.sleep(1)
is_running = True

while is_running:
    # check if the app is running
    is_running = "Calculator" in (p.name() for p in psutil.process_iter())
    print('Process running')

print('Done')
```